# Can you use VIFs in bayesian models?

Tags: bayesian, multicollinearity, variance-inflation-factor

I have created a mixed effect bayesian GLM using rstanarm. I have a few parameters that I suspect to have correlation (or possibly collinearity) issues from looking at a simple correlation matrix. I then used the function check_collinearity on my model to assess the VIFs and found VIF values to be high (over 10 for some parameters). However, I was wondering if VIFs are still valid metrics in a bayesian framework, or if there are other preferable forms of describing collinearity? If VIFs are not used in Bayesian frameworks, why?